# Audio buffer access to downloaded encrypted HLS audio stream

Tags: ios, avfoundation, http-live-streaming, avaudioengine

If I use `AVAssetDownloadTask` to download an encrypted audio-only HLS stream, is it possible to get access to the raw audio data, for the purposes of integrating with `AVAudioEngine`, `AVAudioPlayerNode`, and associated effects? If so, what's the process like for doing that? e.g. could I use an AES library like [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) to decrypt the media?

Thanks!

Comment: hi, interesting, this might have some pointers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096857/decode-audio-samples-from-hls-stream-on-ios

Comment: RNCryptor implements a specific cross-platform format. It's not a general purpose encryption library and can't be used to encrypt or decrypt anything but the RNCryptor format. If you need to perform raw AES decryption, you'll generally want CryptoKit or CommonCrypto. (I haven't explore the HLS encryption format, so I don't know how it's packaged.)